# How to connect to docker postgres server via psql with password the right way and non interactively?

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu, psql

I am trying to connect to a postgres server I have running in a docker container on a nuc. How do I manage this non-interactively so i can have commands run via bash?

OS = 16.04 UBUNTU

Docker container = https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/

The command I use to enter the docker username and docker database in my postgres server:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d docker -U docker
```

As expected I am asked to enter a password which I can do interactively, but I'd like to be able to reference that password from somewhere else safely so I can pass commands to psql to run without having to enter the password. How would I go about this?

As an example I plan to have this run each week to load data:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d docker -U docker --password --c "\COPY ems_stage FROM 'Desktop/ems/ems_raw.csv' WITH (format csv,header);"
```

As a slight workaround, I've been trying to run code without a password as in the psql command:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d docker -U docker -w
```

But I am getting the following error: `psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured out how to do this:

Since I am running psql commands, I placed my password in a .pgpass file as referenced in documentation and then directed the command to the file:

```
PGPASSFILE=.pgpass psql -h localhost -U docker -d docker -w --c "\COPY ems_stage FROM 'Desktop/ems/ems_raw.csv' WITH (format csv,header);"
```

Comment: For me it only worked with added quotes: `PGPASSFILE='/custom/path/.pgpass-customname'`